# Math symbol at end of sentence adds space -> How to avoid?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

When I am using a math symbol at the end of a sentence, LaTeX is adding a space before the period. An example would be:

```
I start a sentence, which I will end with an symbol like $\Omega_{W}$. 
Start of next sentence...
```

=> produces

[image]

How can I suppress this added space between symbol and period?

The according MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
I start a sentence, which I will end with an symbol
like $\Omega_{W}$. Start of next sentence...
\end{document}
```

Comment: to reduce the spacing in this case you can type `$\Omega_{W}\!$.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The space is inserted because of `\scriptspace`, which is automatically added when a math atom has a subscript or superscript. Its default value is 0.5pt and we can see its effect by changing the value:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

I start a sentence, which I will end with an symbol
like $\Omega_{W}$. Start of next sentence...

\scriptspace=20pt

I start a sentence, which I will end with an symbol
like $\Omega_{W}$. Start of next sentence...

I start a sentence, which I will end with an symbol
like $\Omega_{W}\kern-\scriptspace$. Start of next sentence...

\end{document}
```

[image]

The last example shows how to remove the added space (the command is independent of the current value of `\scriptspace`).

This added space doesn't show up in the `\showoutput` listing, because it's added at a different level, precisely when transforming a math list into a horizontal list. See rules 18b, 18c and 18d in the TeXbook, Appendix G.

Comment: +1 also for mine. Very good. Hi David and Egreg.

Comment: Actually the extra space does appear in `\showoutput` but not as a separate entity: one gets `\hbox(5.46666+0.0)x9.70013, shifted 1.79999` for the subscript W, whereas a `\scriptstyle W` gives `\hbox(5.46666+0.0)x9.20013` which is the `0.5pt` narrower.